# c++:defining function which can work as growable array

Tags: c++, arrays

i want growable array for my project. I am trying to define a function that can give me replaced array with new size.I want some idea how can i do this.

```
int growarray[10];
int length =20;
//grow increase size of growarray to 20
void grow(int length){

}
```

Comment: Use `vector<int>` instead.

Comment: What about using simply [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? It's exactly purposed for this case.

Comment: Otherwise, in plain C you would define `growarray` as `int *`, malloc it, and keep its size in a separate variable (possibly in the same struct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::vector would be the ideal way to do this, if you really want to code your own dynamic array you'll need to declare your array on the heap and do something like this...

```
int* growarray = new int[10];
```

and then to "expand" it...

```
int* temp = new int[20];
memcpy(temp, growarray, 10);
delete[] growarray;
growarray = temp;
```

when using this sort of technique you generally expand the array by a constant factor(usually 2 but some libraries use all sorts of different factors)